# Recyclerview Search Filter not working android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My title is coming from retrofit.when I type anything in searchview it doesnt show any result/Suggestion when typed. here is the ss ---> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2pi3.png)

im referring this blog --> https://velmm.com/android-recyclerview-search-filter-example/

help will be appreciated...thanks in advance

Search activity:

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {
SearchView searchView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SearchAdapter slAdapter;
List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    searchView=findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    slAdapter = new SearchAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(slAdapter);

    movieList = new ArrayList<>();

    SLApiSevice service = SLApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(SLApiSevice.class);
    retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call = service.getMySlmodel();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<StartLearning.SlModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Response<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> response) {
            movieList = response.body();
            Log.d("TAG","Response = "+movieList);
            slAdapter.setMovieList(getApplicationContext(),movieList);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG","Response = "+t.toString());



        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            slAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            slAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

Search Adapter

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.CustomViewHolder> implements Filterable {

List<StartLearning.SlModel> Slmdel;
List<StartLearning.SlModel> Slmdel1;

Context context;

public SearchAdapter() {
}

public void setMovieList(Context context, final List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList){
    this.context = context;
    if(this.Slmdel == null){
        this.Slmdel = movieList;
        this.Slmdel1 = movieList;
        notifyItemChanged(0, Slmdel1.size());
    } else {
        final DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return SearchAdapter.this.Slmdel.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return movieList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return SearchAdapter.this.Slmdel.get(oldItemPosition).getTitle() == movieList.get(newItemPosition).getTitle();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

                StartLearning.SlModel newMovie = SearchAdapter.this.Slmdel.get(oldItemPosition);

                StartLearning.SlModel oldMovie = movieList.get(newItemPosition);

                return newMovie.getTitle() == oldMovie.getTitle() ;
            }
        });
        this.Slmdel = movieList;
        this.Slmdel1 = movieList;
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}

public SearchAdapter(Context context,List<StartLearning.SlModel> employees) {
    this.Slmdel = employees;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public SearchAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.startlearning_item, parent, false);

    return new SearchAdapter.CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)+". ");
    holder.employeeName.setText(Slmdel.get(position).getTitle());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(Slmdel != null){
        return Slmdel1.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                Slmdel1 = Slmdel;
            } else {
                List<StartLearning.SlModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (StartLearning.SlModel movie : Slmdel) {
                    if (movie.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(movie);
                    }
                }
                Slmdel1 = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = Slmdel1;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            Slmdel1 = (ArrayList<StartLearning.SlModel>) filterResults.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}



public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView employeeName;
    TextView textView;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        employeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Sl2);
        textView=view.findViewById(R.id.Sl1);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(context, NextSLactivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("title", Slmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("idSLnext", Slmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                //Log.e("ashwini",WAmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

}

List:

```
public class SlModel

{
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public SlModel(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SlModel{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package zon.searchview.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.viewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context; 
    ArrayList<ItemModel> arrayList,arrayListFiltered; 

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemModel> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.arrayListFiltered = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public  viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public  void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(arrayListFiltered.get(position).getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayListFiltered.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;

        public viewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,arrayListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            ArrayList<ItemModel> arrayListFilter = new ArrayList<ItemModel>();

            if(constraint == null|| constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.count = arrayList.size();
                results.values = arrayList;
            } else {
                for (ItemModel itemModel : arrayList) {
                    if(itemModel.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        arrayListFilter.add(itemModel);
                    }
                } 
                results.count = arrayListFilter.size();
                results.values = arrayListFilter;

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            arrayListFiltered = (ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(arrayListFiltered.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };
    return filter;`enter code here`
    }
}
```

For more visit this:- https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/filter-recyclerview-with-searchview.php