# What is the purpose of kotlin-stdlib-jdk dependency?

Tags: android, kotlin

When we create a new project in Android Studio following line is added to the app modules gradle file.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

But what is the purpose of adding this dependency?

I thought it allows us to use Kotlin standard library, but it is not about making Kotlin standard library available to us, since we can use Kotlin standard library functions without it.

Comment: Maybe the Kotlin Standard Library is being included transitively through another dependency (Try `./gradlew dependencies` to see a dependency graph). That would explain why you can remove this explicit dependency and still have access to the Kotlin StdLib.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But what is the purpose of adding this dependency?

It contains the Kotlin standard library.

> we can use Kotlin standard library functions without it

You are getting the Kotlin standard library through a transitive dependency.

For example, in Android Studio 3.5.3, I created a new "Empty Activity" project. I then trimmed back the `dependencies` to:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

However, in the "External Libraries" portion of the explorer tree, I could still see the Kotlin standard library. Running the `dependencies` task shows that the Kotlin standard library is pulled in by `core-ktx` and the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin:

```
releaseRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'release' (target  (androidJvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.61
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.61
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0
|    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.1 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
|    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.50 -> 1.3.61 (*)
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2 -> 1.1.0
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2 -> 1.1.0 (*)
\--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
     \--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3
```

When I removed those two things, now the Kotlin standard library was no longer pulled in as a transitive dependency... and now I don't have access to Kotlin standard library stuff like `listOf()`.

Comment: commonsware ...can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580424/recyclerview-search-filter-not-working-android

Answer (score 2):

In addition to getting Kotlin's stdlib as a transitive dependency (see CommonsWare answer), if you use Kotlin plugin 1.4+ you [will get it from the plugin itself](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library-added-by-default).

This is what running `dependencies` task with empty dependencies section shows:

```
releaseRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'release' (target  (androidJvm)).
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.0
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0
```

Moreover, [starting from Kotlin 1.8 `kotlin-stdlib-jdkX` are merged into `kotlin-stdlib`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target), so if you ever need to declare dependency manually, you should use `kotlin-stdlib`. (note: as seen above, 1.8 version of the plugin still adds `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` dependency. I think this is done to [avoid problems with transitive dependencies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies))

Comment: Good! So the offical document is outdated: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin